# Meta Regression- Average AGe

Tags: meta-analysis, meta-regression

I want to conduct a meta-regression, using the variable.
The studies in my meta-analysis include studies, that compore two indipendent groups.
My question: to calculate average age of a study - is it enough to simply to add up the age of the two indipendent groups and divided it by two? Or are there any other, better ways to get the average age?

Comment: That will give you the average age. But what do you want to do with the average age when you've calculated it?

Comment: I would like to use it as a moderator variable, in a meta-regression.

Comment: and the two samples are usually not the same size, I guess thats a problem

Comment: I found the right solution in the meantime

Comment: Xa= population size of group A
Ya= average of group A
Xb= population size of group B
Yb= average of group B

(Xa/(Xa+Xb))*Ya + (Xb/(Xa+Xb))*Yb = Yc (the average of the combine population)

Answer (score 3):

Your procedure works if the group sizes are equal. If they are not then you need

$$
\frac{n_1 \bar{x_1} + n_2 \bar{x_2}}{n_1 + n_2}
$$
where $n$ is a sample size and $\bar{x}$ is a mean.

But note that if you use this as a moderator in your meta-regression it is only an ecological analysis, you are looking at the effect of being enrolled in a study of people of a certain average age not the effect of age itself.

Comment: Thank you very much! If I want to look at age itself, how should I proceed?

Comment: You need the individual data. Search for the term individual participant data meta-analysis to find out more.

Comment: Thank you very much!